# What information about SMS messages can we get in Direct Boot mode on Android?

Tags: java, android, sms, boot

Here https://developer.android.com/training/articles/direct-boot it says "*Some common use cases for apps needing to run during Direct Boot mode include: ... Apps that provide important user notifications, like SMS apps.*".

I tryed add `android:directBootAware="true"` to my sms broadcast receiver. But while the device is in Direct Boot mode, no SMS comes to the receiver.

I tryed

```
Context directBootContext = appContext.createDeviceProtectedStorageContext();
final Uri SMS_INBOX = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
final Cursor c = directBootContext.getContentResolver().query(SMS_INBOX, null, null, null, null);
```

while in Direct Boot, but got an exception with message `unknown error (code 1294 SQLITE_CANTOPEN_ENOENT[1294]): Could not open database`.

What and how exactly can we get about SMS messages in Direct Boot mode? I'm new to Android, am I missing something? Maybe I need to add a dependency on some library, like here [Receive FCM messages in direct boot mode](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive#enable_direct_boot_mode_message_handling_in_your_app) ?